# How to set up automatic failover to a standby MT cluster from a dedicated cluster?

Tags: cloudant

If I had two dedicated clusters, e.g. one primary and one as a hot backup that are in two different data centers, Cloudant can automatically point to the backup site if my primary site becomes unavailable.

While my business is growing, it is not viable to have two dedicated clusters, so for the short term I am planning to have only one a dedicated Cluster and I replicate to a Multi Tenant cluster for hot standby.  Cloudant are unable to offer automatically pointing to the MT cluster in the event of failure of the primary cluster.

**Question**: what are the main options for building auto failover myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options

1. Install a load balancer (e.g. Amazon ELB) and connect the two clusters:

   - Cloudant cluster A (the primary cluster)
   - Cloudant cluster B (the MT backup cluster)

   The load balancer can then load balance between the two, or do logic like "if I can't see B, send traffic to A".
2. Build functionality to handle switchover in your application layer but arguably using a LB is cleaner (and you can then have it do things like auth and persistent connections).
3. Some sort of DNS switchover service that monitors A and B. IF A becomes unreachable, change DNS to resolve to B instead.